# Drawing points of handwritten stroke using DrawEllipse (GDI+)

Tags: c++, drawing, gdi+, point, drawellipse

I'm working on an application that draws handwritten strokes. Strokes are internally stored as vectors of points and they can be transformed into `std::vector<Gdiplus::Point>`. Points are so close to each other, that simple drawing of each point should result into an image of continual stroke.

I'm using [`Graphics.DrawEllipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (GDI+) method to draw these points. Here's the code:

```
// prepare bitmap:
Bitmap *bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(w, h, PixelFormat32bppRGB);
Graphics graphics(bitmap);

// draw the white background:
SolidBrush myBrush(Color::White);
graphics.FillRectangle(&myBrush, 0, 0, w, h);

Pen blackPen(Color::Black);
blackPen.SetWidth(1.4f);

// draw stroke:
std::vector<Gdiplus::Point> stroke = getStroke();
for (UINT i = 0; i < stroke.size(); ++i)
{
    // draw point:
    graphics.DrawEllipse(&blackPen, stroke[i].X, stroke[i].Y, 2, 2);
}
```

At the end I just save this `bitmap` as a PNG image and sometimes the following problem occurs:

[image: problem]

When I saw this ***"hole" in my stroke***, I decided to draw my points again, but this time, by using ellipse with width and height set to `1` by using `redPen` with width set to `0.1f`. So right after the code above I added the following code:

```
Pen redPen(Color::Red);
redPen.SetWidth(0.1f);

for (UINT i = 0; i < stroke.size(); ++i)
{
    // draw point:
    graphics.DrawEllipse(&redPen, stroke[i].X, stroke[i].Y, 1, 1);
}
```

And the new stoke I've got looked like this:
[image: problem2]

When I use [`Graphics.DrawRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `DrawEllipse` while drawing this new red stroke, it never happens that this stroke (drawn by drawing rectangles) would have different width or holes in it:

[image: rectangles]

I can't think of any possible reason, why drawing circles would result into this weird behaviour. How come that stroke is always continual and never deformed in any way when I use [`Graphics.DrawRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?
 Could anyone explain, what's going on here? Am I missing something?

By the way I'm using Windows XP (e.g. in case it's a known bug). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made the wrong assumption that if I use [`Graphics.DrawEllipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to draw a circle with radius equal to 2px with pen of width about 2px, it will result in a filled circle with diameter about 4-5 px being drawn.
But I've found out that I actually can't rely on the width of the pen while drawing  a circle this way. This method is meant only for drawing of border of this shape, thus for drawing filled ellipse it's much better to use [`Graphics.FillEllipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Another quite important fact to consider is that both of mentioned functions take as parameters coordinates that specify ***"upper-left corner of the rectangle that specifies the boundaries of the ellipse"***, so I should subtract half of the radius from both coordinates to make sure the original coordinates specify the middle of this circle.

Here's the new code:

```
// draw the white background:
SolidBrush whiteBrush(Color::White);
graphics.FillRectangle(&whiteBrush, 0, 0, w, h);

// draw stroke:
Pen blackBrush(Color::Black);
std::vector<Gdiplus::Point> stroke = getStroke();
for (UINT i = 0; i < stroke.size(); ++i)
    graphics.FillEllipse(&blackBrush, stroke[i].X - 2, stroke[i].Y - 2, 4, 4);

// draw original points:
Pen redBrush(Color::Red);
std::vector<Gdiplus::Point> origStroke = getOriginalStroke();
for (UINT i = 0; i < origStroke.size(); ++i)
    graphics.FillRectangle(&redBrush, origStroke[i].X, origStroke[i].Y, 1, 1);
```

which yields following result:

[image: correct stroke]

So in case someone will face the same problem as I did, the solution is:

[image]